# Can't access socket from external device on Android

Tags: android, sockets, proxy

I wrote a simple HTTP-Proxy for Android which is listening on the device external IP Address and a specific port (e.g. 192.168.1.20:8080).

I can access IP/port from the device itself - but any tries from external devices will never be accepted in the run-loop.

The simplified code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements Runnable {

    private ServerSocket socket;
    private int port = 8080;
    private Thread thread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        String ip = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());

        Log.v("TAG", "http://"+ip+":"+port);
        try {
            Log.v("TAG", InetAddress.getByName(ip).toString());
            socket = new ServerSocket(port, 5, InetAddress.getByName(ip));
            socket.setSoTimeout(5000);

            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket client = socket.accept();
                //  Never reaches this line if connected externally
                Log.d("TAG", "client connected");
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also added the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But still no luck. Anybody out there who can give advise?

Thx.

Comment: Why are you binding your ServerSocket to an ip address? Just specify the port. Nothing else.

Comment: You should put Logs in every catch block and print the stacktrace. I wonder how instantiating the ServerSocket on the main thread could work. Put it in a thread too.

Comment: I need to bind it on the external IP so I could connect to the phone from other devices in the same net (one intention is to work as a proxy for chromecast to bypass invalid SSL certificates - so the chromecast needs to connect to the phone)

Comment: You do not have to bind the server socket to an ip for that. Try without.

Comment: Many thx @greenapps! Both comments are true - starting the socket from a thread solved the problem. I wonder why it worked for internal connections but not for external ones - maybe I stripped down too much and got another problem somewhere...